# POI 5.0.0 - get NoSuchMethodError - CTPPrDefault.getPPr() - CTPPrGeneral

Tags: apache-poi

After moving to POI 5.0.0 I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrDefault.getPPr()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTPPrGeneral;
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyles.setStyles(XWPFStyles.java:145)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFStyles.onDocumentRead(XWPFStyles.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:207)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:169)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:126)
```

Where is this CTPPrGeneral class placed?
I tried poi-ooxml-full 5.0.0, poi-ooxml-lite 5.0.0, poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 - There is no CTPPrGeneral class.

Searching in Google does not help. It looks like it mentioned only in XWPFDefaultParagraphStyle class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new Apache POI 5.0.0 needs `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar`. Both contain `org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTPPrGeneral` and `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrDefault` has a method `getPPr()` which returns `CTPPrGeneral`.

Your problem results from the fact that there is `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` or older also in class path. And there `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPPrDefault` has a method `getPPr()` which returns `CTPPr` and **not** `CTPPrGeneral`. That's why `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. The Apache POI 5.0.0 code calls `CTPPrDefault.getPPr` and expects a `CTPPrGeneral` but the old `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` exports `CTPPrDefault` which has `getPPr` **not** returning that type.

Make sure your classpath **only** contains `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` but **not** `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` or even older versions of `ooxml-schemas` when Apache POI 5.0.0 is used.

Comment: adding to Axels answer: we've upgraded to ECMA 376 edition 5 - as mentioned in the [changes](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html), expect API breaks when using the XmlBeans directly

Comment: Thank you very much. Excluding ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar has fixed the problem. And it is true, without ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar there were lots of code broken, in low-level CT... classes as described. Mostly quite easy to fix.

Comment: Hi--I'm trying to exclude the `ooxml-schemas` dependency using the following statement under the `xdocreport` reference: `exclude("org.apache.poi", "ooxml-schemas")` but this issue isn't going away. Can you please provide an example gradle config that shows you you excluded `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar`?

Comment: @Alex: This question is about `apache poi 5.0.0`. But you cannot use `XDocReport` with  `apache poi 5.0.0` as `XDocReport` needs `ooxml-schemas`. So excluding will not work. Simply do not including `apache poi 5.0.0` if `XDocReport` needs to be used and vice versa.

Comment: Current XDocReport is now able to work together with Apache POI 5.