# Error exporting from DOCX to PDFjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I am using these dependecies in a maven project, to export a pdf and excel files:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to use the poi-ooxml to use some other functionalities on my site. But when I use it I get this error:

> Error exporting from DOCX to PDFjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTStyle.getDefault()Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/STOnOff$Enum;

I have seen some previous questions here and I think there is a question that may fit this problem, but I don't know how the solution can be applied.

[POI 5.0.0 - get NoSuchMethodError - CTPPrDefault.getPPr() - CTPPrGeneral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66870741/poi-5-0-0-get-nosuchmethoderror-ctpprdefault-getppr-ctpprgeneral)

As you can see it seems that the project is using some old packages (**ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar**) and in my maven dependenecies there is the same package, so I think the error could be the same. Correct me if I am not right, please.

**My question is: Is there any way to prevent maven from downloading this package?**

I have already tried to add this dependency, to avoid using old dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: What library are you using to convert DOCX to PDF? If it is `fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core` (XDocReport) then this needs `ooxml-schemas` and so cannot work together with `apache poi 5` which cannot use `ooxml-schemas`. Latest version of XDocReport can only work togethwer with `apache poi 4` and `ooxml-schemas 1.4`.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have changed the apache poi to version 4 and it works